# Div to img HTML2Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to convert a div to img using html2canvas, the problem after this process the final image ignores me images in the div and only show  text:
https://gist.github.com/martinop/cc20969f49b2bb116617
https://gist.github.com/martinop/5fd0199d800ee2ffe313

if i use other way like background-img in the css with my testid, when I click in the button i have this error:
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported

Comment: Without looking at the code it sounds like you are falling victim to the Same Origin Policy. Afaik there is no way to include images from other domains this way in a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give full path of image in order to create image of div using htm2canvas

FOR I.E.

```
<img src="https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/10482079?s=140" class="img">
```

I have test this and its work for me.
It's worked on chrome too... Run code snippet in chrome

```js
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#load').click(function(){
            html2canvas($('#testdiv'), {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
                    window.open(img);
                }
            });


    });
});
```

```css
div#testdiv
{
    height:500px;
    width:500px;
    position: relative; 
}
 
.fuente{
 font-family: 'Chewy', cursive;
 margin-left: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}
h1{
 color: #EE1F3B;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
    font-size: 70px;
 
}
.img{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}
.imgequipo{
   position: absolute; 
   top: 90px; 
   left: 335px; 
  width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 
}
h2{
   position: absolute; 
   top: 110px; 
   font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
   color: #ffe400;
   font-size:80px;
   font-weight: bold;
   left: 30px;   
 
}
 
body{
 margin-top: 100px;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
 background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/build/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class ="container">
<h1 class="fuente text-center">prueba</h1>
<div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-3">
<div id="testdiv">
<img src="https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/10482079?s=140" class="img">
<img src="https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/10482079?s=140" class="imgequipo">
<h2>prueba2</h2>
</div><br>
<button  id="load" class="btn btn-info">Generar Imagen</button>
</div>
</div>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its working over here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvJLBJ too. so i think your chrome version might be older version. Please upgrade chrome and check it out.

Comment: i have the v  43.0.2357.132 m